# Wigner function of $|n\rangle\langle m|$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-optics, wigner-transform

For $n=m$, the Wigner function is given by,
$$
W_n(\alpha) = \frac{2}{\pi} (-1)^n \exp(-2 |\alpha|^2) L_n(4 |\alpha|^2),
$$

And for $n \neq m $, it is,
$$
f_{mn}=\sqrt{\frac{m!}{n!}} e^{i(m-n) \arctan\left(  p/x\right)  }
\frac{\left(  -1\right)^{m}}{\pi\hbar}\left ( \frac{x^{2}+p^{2}}{\hbar/2}
\right ) ^ {\left(  n-m\right)  /2} L_{m}^{n-m}\left( 
\frac{x^{2}+p^{2}}{\hbar/2}\right)  
e^{-\left( x^{2}+p^{2}\right)  /\hbar}
$$
and in this case, there will be always a
$e^{i(m-n) \arctan\left(  p/x\right)}$ term. But the Wigner function is a real valued function. How to reconcile this?

Comment: What is $f_{mn}$?

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/362658/what-is-the-wigner-function-of-n-rangle-langle-m?rq=1). Note this operator is not Hermitian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have been misinformed!

Only diagonal members of the Wigner function matrix are provably real. You just illustrated off-diagonal elements are complex, in general, as your text must state.

In general, Wigner transforms of Hermitian operators are real,
$$
g(x,p)= \hbar \int \!\! dy ~ e^{-iyp} \langle x+\hbar y/2| \hat G |x-\hbar y /2  \rangle , \implies  \\
g(x,p)^*= \hbar \int \!\! dy ~ e^{iyp} \langle x+\hbar y/2| \hat G |x-\hbar y /2  \rangle ^* \\
 =\hbar \int \!\! dy ~ e^{iyp} \langle x-\hbar y/2| \hat G ^\dagger |x+\hbar y /2  \rangle ,
$$
so $g=g^*$ for $\hat G= \hat G^\dagger$, like WF diagonal elements, otherwise not. $|m\rangle \langle n|$ is not hermitian.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. Also I came across this equation while going through your book :)

Comment: It says that, in so many words....  cf (91).