# Similar to Dirac Equation, could Maxwell Equations be derived by (first) quantization of energy-momentum relation (for describing a single photon)?

Tags: maxwell-equations, dirac-equation

First I ask this because of similar (mathematical) structures of these relativistic wave equations.

In addition, by quantization definitely I don't mean a canonical (or second) quantization. 
Moreover, if we also accept that a 1-spin single photon is described quantum mechanically by Maxwell equations, similar to Dirac equation which quantum mechanically describe a single electron (or any single 1/2-spin particle). In this regard, a more explicit discussion could be found in this page: [What equation describes the wavefunction of a single photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/437/what-equation-describes-the-wavefunction-of-a-single-photon?noredirect=1&lq=1) .

Comment: I think the similarity arises because they are both Lorentz covariant, not from any quantisation precedure.

Comment: @John Rennie Thank you John for your comment. I added a note to the question. By quantization I mean a first quantization procedure simply.